# JMX_exporter shows error in Prometheus & Grafana

Tags: jmx, grafana, prometheus

I have used JMX exporter to monitor Java application deployed based on jetty .

I have  downloaded the  `jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.1.0.jar` file

Deployed the java application with jmx_exporter command

```
nohup java -javaagent:./jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.1.0.jar=7101:config.yaml -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormContentSize=10000000 -Xms256m -Xmx256m -Djava.io.tmpdir=epoch_temp_dir -jar jetty-runner-9.0.7.v20131107.jar --log yyyy_mm_dd-java-application-1-request.log --out yyyy_mm_dd-java-application-1-output.log --port 8091 --path /java-application-1 java-app1.war >> java-application-1.log 2>&1 &
```

config.yaml

```
 #cat config.yaml
---
startDelaySeconds: 0
jmxUrl: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://127.0.0.1:7101/jmxrmi
ssl: false
lowercaseOutputName: true
lowercaseOutputLabelNames: true
rules:
- pattern: ".*"
```

**Prometheus shows connection timed out**  in status page

**output log :** of the java application deployed

```
io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.jmx.JmxCollector collect
SEVERE: JMX scrape failed: java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error du
ring JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is:
        java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out]
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:369)
        at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:270)
        at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.jmx.JmxScraper.doScrape(JmxScraper.java:106)
        at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.jmx.JmxCollector.collect(JmxCollector.java:415)
        at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.client.CollectorRegistry$MetricFamilySamplesEnumeration.findNextElement(CollectorRegistry.java:180)
        at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.client.CollectorRegistry$MetricFamilySamplesEnumeration.nextElement(CollectorRegistry.java:213)
        at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.client.CollectorRegistry$MetricFamilySamplesEnumeration.nextElement(CollectorRegistry.java:134)
        at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.client.exporter.common.TextFormat.write004(TextFormat.java:22)
        at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.client.exporter.HTTPServer$HTTPMetricHandler.handle(HTTPServer.java:59)
        at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)
        at sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:83)
        at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:82)
        at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:675)
        at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)
        at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:647)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is:
        java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out]
        at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup(RegistryContext.java:136)
        at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.lookup(GenericURLContext.java:205)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServerJNDI(RMIConnector.java:1955)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServer(RMIConnector.java:1922)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:287)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is:
        java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:304)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:342)
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
```

Opened the 7101 ports in the client server and grant access to Prometheus server.

Prometheus Server RAM usage:

```
# free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           4.8G        1.9G        118M        256M        2.8G        2.3G
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

Client server RAM :

```
# free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           9.8G        3.7G        435M         16M        5.6G        5.7G
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

`Curl localhost:7101` in the client server is not responding

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the jmxUrl from the config, that's not required for agent use.

Comment: Hi Brian. I am getting the exact same error and I don't have that jmxUrl in my config. Any idea what is going wrong here please?

Comment: You should remove also the "hostPort" conf param. Because, if present, it will be used in order to build the jmxUrl that, as reported by brian, is not required for agent use.